# How to play FLV files in mediaelement.js player?

Tags: media-player, mediaelement.js, flv

What is the mistake I made in the following code to play FLV file?

I just changed the source tag only...

```
<video id="player1" width="640" height="360" style="max-width:100%;" poster="http://www.mediaelementjs.com/images/big_buck_bunny.jpg" preload="none" controls playsinline webkit-playsinline>
    <!--<source src="https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/CastVideos/mp4/BigBuckBunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">-->
    <source src="./video/sample.flv" type="video/flv">
</video>

<script src="../build/mediaelement-and-player.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yeah, what is the mistake? Is there any error message you forgot to share?

Comment: FLV file doesn't play and I got an message: "This type of video file isn't supported."

Comment: Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats - obviously, FLV videos are not supported, as the error message tells you ;)